# Set xrange for time correctly

Tags: gnuplot

I try to plot a file containing timestamps of the format `YEAR-MONTH-DAY HOUR` and an positive integer separated by a tabulator. GNUPlot seems unable to extract the start end endtime of the given file telling me

> Warning: empty x range [6.31152e+08:6.31152e+08], adjusting to [6.2484e+08:6.37464e+08]

But even telling the xrange explicitly does not improve the result

> "sumChangePlot.p", line 12: Can't plot with an empty x range!

This is the related code of my plot file

```
set datafile separator "\t"
set xdata time
set timefmt '%y-%m-%d %H'
set xrange ['2014-11-06 00':'2014-11-12 24']
```

and this is an excerpt of my data file (containing data of this type until the 12th)

```
2014-11-6 19    1
2014-11-6 20    1
2014-11-6 21    2
2014-11-6 22    2
2014-11-6 23    2
```

**How can I make GNUPlot understand the xrange given in the file?** (prefered automatically but if manually is the only choice so be it)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to use a four-digit year you must use `%Y` (capital letter) in the format string:

```
set datafile separator "\t"
set xdata time
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H'
set xrange ['2014-11-06 00':'2014-11-12 24']
plot 'file.txt' using 1:2
```

Answer (score 0):

Mabe You Can Try   %%y-%%m-%%d %%H

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33886904)